# CRF for NER with many classes

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, crf

I'm going to develop named-entity recognition system with many (100+) classes. Assuming that they have roughly equal frequency, what algorithm should perform best? According to my understanding (sadly, far away from ideal) of how CRF works, it should be ok here. But in some sources ([google books](http://books.google.com.ua/books?id=opn1BDfvs-0C&pg=PA582&lpg=PA582&dq=conditional%20random%20field%20%22many%20classes%22&source=bl&ots=wsuxmGzVlB&sig=h-8DuUcKuxMjiLN7UgV6b6KraeM&hl=uk&sa=X&ei=nXfmU87kIMWc0AW9mID4BQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=conditional%20random%20field%20%22many%20classes%22&f=false)) I found another opinion.

So, is CRF suitable algorithm for NER with huge number of classes?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of classes are we talking about here? Don't be coy :)

You're probably best off using a hierarchical approach:

1. Have a small number of root classes, like "product", "person", "place". First pass figures out which one is which.
2. Then for each of the root classes, have sub-classes like "car product", "electronics product", etc.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know those classes. They will be "machine learned" and human-unfriendly. I want to find the "atomic" (in sense of meaning) part-of-text (like subject/predicate/verb, but bit more general. Nonetheless, I think these meanings will overlap a lot). For example: "<subject>We</subject> <notification>are pleased to inform</notification> <object>you<object> <preposition>that</preposition> <topic>you have won the lottery</topic>"

Comment: You need to know the classes for NER. I would start with POS tagging. You can use Stanford's CoreNLP for this. http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml

Comment: Yes, I use POS tags as features. Also, in stanford-nlp-users mailing I got answer for `CRF efficiency for many classes` - CRF can't handle that. I got advice to use Conditional Markov Model, but I need some time for research.